# How can I authenticate to request Firebase REST api to fetch the list of firebase projects of a signed-in user?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I wish to fetch the list of firebase projects of a signed-in user (not me) on my website.
**I can't seem to request the firebase rest api correctly ([endpoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/list)) as I receive a 401 UNAUTHENTICATED error.**

The steps I follow:

I am using `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup` on my browser to authenticate users. Here are the scopes used:

```
// Google provider
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
// Additionnal scopes
provider.addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform");
provider.addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase");
provider.addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore");
// Signin
signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
```

I am then using `getIdToken` method to get a token from the user.
`const token = await auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true);`

I use this token to request `https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects`:

```
const data = await window.fetch("https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects", {
     headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  })
  .then(res => res.json());
```

but I am always getting a 401 error:

```
{
  "error": {
      "code": 401,
      "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
      "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of Firebase projects for a user you need an OAuth2 token for a user that is a collaborator on the projects. You are trying to use the ID token/JWT for a Firebase Authentication user, which is not the same.

Follow the documentation on [generating an access token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/workflow_set-up-and-manage-project?platform=android#generate-access-token) to get value that you can use to get a list of projects.

Comment: How would I fetch the firebase projects of a signed-in user? (not MY firebase projects) The application "Firefoo" (a firestore GUI client) is doing exactly that, you login with scopes and they fetch your firebase projects.

Comment: Still the same: you need to get an OAuth2 token for that user with the requires scopes to request their project list.  A Firebase Authentication user is **not** necessarily a collaborator on the projects. For an example, this is how the Firebase CLI does this: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/0dd344dde1e274e0845c0a13733d5b2f07bef587/src/auth.ts#L437-L455

Comment: Thank you! It's helping but I am not quite there yet.
The documentation link is not helping since it explains how to obtain an api token to be able to fetch my own list of projects (it doesn't have the user element in it)
What I have right now is an idToken of a user which accepted the scopes/permissions for me to see his projects.
From here I am still not sure how to create the final OAuth2 accessToken. Should I use the user information, the idToken and the scopes to create a JWT token myself?

Comment: This always gets the OAuth2 token for the current user. So when you run the code that is you; and when one of your users runs the code, it'll get the token for them.

Comment: This method `admin.credential.applicationDefault().getAccessToken()` is from `firebase-admin` and it is only accessible server side. How can it know about the current user which signed-in on the client side?

Comment: You'll have to extract the code that gets the OAuth token with the right scopes from the SDK so you can run it for your users (instead of for yourself). The link I gave is the closest I could find (this definitely used to be easier to find in firebase-tools in the past), but it is a standard Google sign-in with some additional scopes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237292/discussion-between-httpete-and-frank-van-puffelen).

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer, the firebase SDK does give you an accessToken with the idToken. You can then use this token instead of the idToken for any of your REST api needs.

```js
const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
// This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
```